Implementing a Stack using Two Queues: Push vs. Pop Efficiency
I'm implementing a LIFO stack using two queues and have come across two methods: one where the push operations are costly (moving elements between queues during push) and another where the pop operations are costly (moving elements during pop). Can someone explain the practical advantages and disadvantages of each method, and in what scenarios one might be preferred over the other?

Why implement a stack using two queues when you could achieve O(1) time complexity for both push and pop operations using a LinkedList?

seems VERY SIMILAR to the (closed) question Implementing a Queue using Two Stacks: Enqueue vs. Dequeue Efficiency ?!?  Just LIFO <-> FIFO and a different user :-|

There is no real scenario in which it would be appropriate to implement a stack using 2 queues. I don't generally like to weigh the pros and cons of things you'd never want to do, but I'll answer this question just because AI always seems to get it wrong.
If you were forced to do it for some reason, it would almost always be better to make the push cheap and the pop expensive, if the total costs are similar in both cases.
The reason for this is simply that you can push more elements that you pop, but you can't pop more elements than you push.  AI will incorrectly tell you that it depends on which operation is most frequent.
